# Declare COUNT value as variable (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, variables, count, plpgsql

Does anyone know if it possible to declare the COUNT value as a variable to call in queries/functions/triggers?

I would like to use the COUNT value to trigger data transfer from table1 to table2, triggering when the row count of table1 reaches 500.

FIX.....

Defining count function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_function () RETURNS integer AS $$  
     BEGIN
     RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1);
    END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Calling the variable to trigger an event:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_table2()
    RETURNS trigger AS
    $$
    BEGIN
    IF count_function()>=500 THEN
    INSERT INTO table2
    values ('NEW.column1','NEW.column2');
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
    END $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER copy_trigger 
    AFTER INSERT ON table1 
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_table2();
```

Comment: Your function returns an integer, not a table. It is unclear exactly what you want to do, but a scalar function would be called as `select count_function()`.

Comment: Apart from anything else, you need to add "RETURN Cnt;" before the END statement...

Comment: I would like to define the count value as a variable (integer). I want to use this value to trigger an event - when the count = 500. So I do want to return an integer value.

Comment: @mlinth thanks for your help

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried executing the procedure in save_table2() as suggested in the answer by pid, but I get an error at EXECUTE PROCEDURE

Comment: I haven't done this in a long time, but I'm absolutely certain that when you use `values ('new.column1','new.column2')` instead of `values (NEW.column1, NEW.column2)` it will try to insert the raw strings, instead of the data from the columns you want.

Comment: @coladict thanks for your suggestion. I tried it with capitals and it had no effect. If you can think of anything else that might be the cause, it will be much appreciated!

Comment: My suggestion wasn't the capitals, it was removing the quotes.

Comment: @coladict my bad. When I remove the quotes I got a different error... ERROR: column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type text . Then I realised I have a id column too which is numeric which makes sense! so I added that to the list (NEW.id, NEW.column1, NEW.column2)... but now I get the error record "new" is not assigned yet. The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate. PL/pgSQL function save_table2() line 4 at SQL statement. So it must be something to do with the values I am inputting

Comment: I figured out what was wrong... I deleted the ID column, to simplify the problem so all that was left was text. But I forgot I had a clear function and trigger to delete the rows off table1 that was refering to id. I've deleted the clear function and trigger to see if the save_table2() works and it now copies the row from table1 to table 2 when the count row of table1 is over a certain value :). Now to work out how to get the clear function to work. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this (should work on MySQL and SQL Server, maybe PostgreSQL, too)?

```
SELECT count_function();
```

On Oracle it would be

```
SELECT count_function() FROM DUAL;
```

To store the result in a variable you can do this:

```
DECLARE result int;

SET result = SELECT count_function();
```

In your case the trigger can be written as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER copy_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON table1 
FOR EACH STATEMENT 
WHEN count_function() >= 500
EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_table2 ();
```

Notice that `>=` means *greater or equal*. While `=>` does not exist (or is not what it looks like).

If nothing else helps, you can do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_table2_on_500()
RETURNS VOID AS $$
  DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN

    cnt := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1);

    IF cnt >= 500 THEN
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_table2();
    END IF;

END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER copy_trigger_on_500
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_table2_on_500();
```

**EDIT**: What was wrong with the code

I've used the keyword `PROCEDURE` because it is very common on various database systems (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL). But it is not legit on PostgreSQL.

On PostgreSQL you must use `FUNCTION` and specify the return type `VOID`, which I think is kind of a contradiction, but I'm digressing on details here.

The full explanation of [function vs procedure is here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/stored_procedures_functions).

The difference is mainly that a function returns always a scalar value while a procedure may return nothing (`VOID`), a scalar value or a data table. It is more flexible but also has other caveats. Refer to the link above for more details.

Comment: ah yes this does work, although can I call a function as a variable in a trigger?

Comment: Yes, you can call a function from another function and store the result in a variable.

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that I personally would store the value 500 in a table, so you can change it easily without having to edit the function.

Comment: @pid Thanks for your help everyone! I tried the above code, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Executing the procedure within the trigger causes an error near the WHEN count_function() and executing in the function brings an syntax error at EXECUTE PROCEDURE.

Comment: I just noticed this is a procedure rather than function? what's the difference between the two? I tried function that didn't work. Trying procedure I get an error at REPLACE PROCEDURE

Comment: I fixed some parts of the code. The EXECUTE should work now, let me know if there are other problems!

Comment: @pid I really appreciate your help thanks. I tried using CREATE FUNCTION with RETURN VOID, but then I can't connect the trigger to the function because it isn't set to RETURN TRIGGER (ERROR: function save_table2() does not exist). When I tried with RETURN TRIGGER AS $$.... and RETURN NEW.. I get ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "new.column1". QUERY: INSERT INTO table2 values ('new.column1','new.column2') CONTEXT: P:/pgSQL function save_table2() line 4 at SQL statement

Comment: Managed to get it working executing trigger for each row. Thank you for your help today!

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function not the variable from the function:
`SELECT count_function ()`
Also in the function you do not need the variable and have this:
`RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1);`

Comment: Yes it does thanks! I'm now just stuck on how to use this function value to trigger an event

Comment: In Postgres there are trigger function that you can use:`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_name()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$  
BEGIN  
    IF count_function()>= 500 THEN
         insert into table...;
      END IF;
    RETURN NEW;  
END;  
$$  
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'; `

Comment: and create the trigger:`CREATE TRIGGER copy_trigger
  AFTER INSERT 
  ON table1
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function();` In my previous comment, the name of the function is wrong, it should be trigger_function() instead of trigger_name

Comment: Ok so I tried the above trigger function along with trigger:

        CREATE TRIGGER save_table2_trigger 
        AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1 
        FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_table2();

But I got the error ... invalid input syntax for integer "new.type"

Comment: that error is saying that something is expected to be integer, but it's probably varchar, in that case you should do an explicit cast ''::integer;

Comment: the data from columns1 and columns2 that I am copying from table1 to table2 is text?

Comment: If it's the same in the destination table, it shouldn't throw an error

Comment: the data types for table1 and 2 are definitely the same -text based. but going off the error it says it should be an integer?

Comment: The error might not be in the destination table, it might be somewhere during the triggering process.

Comment: Managed to get it working executing trigger for each row. Thank you for your help today!

Comment: You're welcome! Just out of curiosity, what was the issue?

Comment: The integer error was because I forgot I had an ID column using integers. After I removed the id columns, I got another issue. I managed to get it working by changing the FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE to FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE.